# Find normal standard deviation from the cdf at a specific point and the distribution mean

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, cdf

I have three points of data:

1. My distribution is normal
2. The distribution has a mean which I know (m), and
3. I know the cdf (p) of the distribution at another point (x).

From this, I want to find the standard deviation (std) of the function.  I'm trying to solve this using scipy's integrate and fsolve, but this isn't working so far.

Specifically, I've tried:

```
def func(std, x, m, p):
     return integrate.quad(np.exp(-(t-m)**2/std**2), -10000, x) - p

x0 = fsolve(func, 2 args=(3, 0, 0.96))
```

I have this feeling that I'm approaching this problem incorrectly.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing it completely wrong, it should be:

```
def func(std, x, m, p):
    return (norm.cdf(x, m, std) - p)

fsolve(func, 3, args=(0, -5, 0.8))
```